# Get filesize on array of files from subfolder?

Tags: php, filesize

I'm stuck, i have this script that lists files in the folder ./downloads which is a subfolder from where this index.php file resides, everything works great except getting the filesize for each file returns 0 on all files, any idea why?

```
        // Opens directory
    $myDirectory=opendir("./downloads");

    // Gets each entry
    while($entryName=readdir($myDirectory)) {
      $dirArray[]=$entryName;
    }

    // Finds extensions of files
    function findexts ($filename) {
      $filename=strtolower($filename);
      $exts=split("[/\\.]", $filename);
      $n=count($exts)-1;
      $exts=$exts[$n];
      return $exts;
    }

    // Closes directory
    closedir($myDirectory);

    // Counts elements in array
    $indexCount=count($dirArray);

    // Sorts files
    sort($dirArray);

    // Loops through the array of files
    for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {

      // Gets File Names
      $name=$dirArray[$index];
      $namehref=$dirArray[$index];

      // Gets Extensions 
      $extn=findexts($dirArray[$index]); 

      // Gets file size 
      $size=number_format(filesize($dirArray[$index]));

      // Print 'em
      print("
      <tr class='$class'>
        <td><a href='./downloads/$namehref'>$name</a></td>
        <td><a href='./downloads/$namehref'>$extn</a></td>
        <td><a href='./downloads/$namehref'>$size</a></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>");
      }
    }
```

To my surprise both filenames and extensions are properly displayed yet filesize returns 0 and i have no idea why.

Comment: can you create a minimal viable example, there is a lot of erroneous code in here

Comment: ok i deleted stuff that's not relevant, but i'm trying to understand why filesize returns 0 when both get file names and get extensions return the proper values, the function you may want to look at is where comment '// Gets file size  ' is located

Comment: im testing it locally, let you know ..

Comment: works for me. file-size displayed. what OS are you running this on?

Comment: really huh? running on ubuntu 14.04 but the thing is, the path i'm running the script on is actually a UNC mounted smb share from a windows machine, could it be that php does need higher privileges to see filesize rather then to just see the names and extensions? this is the privleges set on a file in the downloads directory: -rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 8292233 Nov 26 17:03 1.mp4, should be sufficient i thought or is php being run by another process/user than www-data?

Comment: very strange, if i change the opendir to look in the local directory instead as : $myDirectory=opendir("."); then filesize works as well, but not if files are in the downloads directory, the permission for both files and directories in linux are the same.

Comment: must be something specific to it be a smb share Server Fault may have better people to ask